# Stored procedure in SQL used with substring

Tags: sql

I have this stored procedure here:

```
else if(substring(@SMS,1,1)='S')
begin
insert into WEB_POROSIA..SMS_SERVISI(IDTICKET, MBYLLUR) values(convert(int,substring(@SMS,2,len(@sms)-1)),1)
select @sms
end
```

What it does is: I send a SMS like this:

**S 23** and in the database it saves the **23** value..

Now, it works like this but not if I **add a letter** before:
i.e

**S B21** it should insert **B21** to the table...

How to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
values(convert(int,substring(@SMS,2,len(@sms)-1)),1)
               ^ Because you are converting it into int
```

You can `convert` into `varchar` if you to get **B**

```
values(convert(varchar,substring(@SMS,2,len(@sms)-1)),1)
```

(Assuming you will `alter` the table and change the `datetype` from `int` to `varchar`)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove the conversion to int:

```
insert into WEB_POROSIA..SMS_SERVISI(IDTICKET, MBYLLUR) values(substring(@SMS,2,len(@sms)-1),1)
```

You may also need to modify the type on the target column if that is also using int.